# SQL Server using procedure to calculate column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a procedure that calculates the price of travel based on some values from other tables.

Procedure looks like:

```
create procedure CalculateTravelPrice(@ID int)
as
begin
return
(select SalaryForOneDay from Driver where driver.PersonID=@ID)+
(select SalaryForOneDay from Driver where driver.PersonID=@ID)
end
```

I'm trying to add column that uses this procedure to calculate the value:

```
alter table RegisteredTravel
add PriceForTravel as (CalculateTravelPrice(RegTravelID))
```

but I get error saying

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
>   'CalculateTravelPrice' is not a recognized built-in function name."

So the question is how to correctly use procedure to calculate this value? Is this even a good practice or maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Just a note: Is there a typo in your sql? - the two parts of your query are identical. You'd be better to just do x2 if this is the case and save a data read.

Comment: I suspect you will be MUCH faster with a Join here !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should turn your proc into a udf (user defined function). You can then use that for your calculated column. I don't think procs can be used this way.

Comment: I changed my procedure to function, but still the same error -  'CalculateTravelPrice' is not a recognized built-in function name. Am I calling this function wrong or what?

Comment: functions need to include the schema in their call, so try changing the column definition to: `add PriceForTravel as (dbo.CalculateTravelPrice(RegTravelID))`

Comment: Thanks, just figured this out by myself 1 min ago :D

Comment: no worries. Just watch the performance of this though when selecting lots of rows - udfs can be a slow way of computing columns.

Comment: Just a quick question for understanding - does SQL recauculates all Price values each time I select from this table? So maybe it is better to use view for all prices?

Comment: Yes - it will recalculate each time its called. This might also be bad for you as your data will update as your "SalaryForOneDay" updates. I would think that would be incorrect as you would want the cost to be accurate at the time of Travel. You may want to think about having a proper column, and filling it with an after insert trigger instead. Even with a view you'll have trouble capturing the cost as it was at the time the travel occurred.